# Choose which variable to solve for (Python root finding using fsolve)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, equation-solving

Scipy offers many useful tools for root finding, notably [fsolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html).  Typically a program has the following form:

```
def eqn(x, a, b):
    return x + 2*a - b**2

fsolve(eqn, x0=0.5, args = (a,b))
```

and will find a root for `eqn(x) = 0` given some arguments `a` and `b`.

However, what if I have a problem where I want to solve for the `a` variable, giving the function arguments in `x` and `b`? Of course, I could recast the initial equation as

```
def eqn(a, x, b)
```

but this seems long winded and inefficient.  Instead, is there a way I can simply set `fsolve` (or another root finding algorithm) to allow me to choose which variable I want to solve for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go with your first idea in a more concise way using [lambda functions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk):

```
fsolve(lambda a,x,b: eqn(x, a, b), x0=0.5, args=(x,b))
```

That is, rearrange the arguments in the lambda wrapper so you don't have to write a separate `def eqn2(a,x,b)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly quicker than a complete function redefinition, but still feels unpythonic, especially when there are many variables to choose from which would require many lambda functions to be defined. Is there an alternative way?